# Error when installing Periscope

Tags: pi-2

I've created a media system with my Pi 2, but when I install Periscope using `sudo pip install periscope`, I obtain this error::

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): periscope in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/periscope-0.2.4-py3.4.egg
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup>=3.2.0 (from periscope)
Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-c4qm9_4y/BeautifulSoup/setup.py) 
egg_info for package BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-c4qm9_4y/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-c4qm9_4y/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22

print "Unit tests have failed!"

                              ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-
c4qm9_4y/BeautifulSoup
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

The Contents of `/root/.pip/pip.log`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Thu Aug 17 20:01:51 2017
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): periscope in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/periscope-0.2.4-py3.4.egg
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup>=3.2.0 (from periscope)
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup/
URLs to search for versions for BeautifulSoup>=3.2.0 (from periscope):
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup/
Found link 
https://pypi.python.org/packages/1e/ee/
295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-
3.2.1.tar.gz#md5=44656527ef3ac9874ac4d$
Found link 
https://pypi.python.org/packages/33/fe/
15326560884f20d792d3ffc7fe8f639aab88647c9d46509a240d9bfbb6b1/BeautifulSoup-
3.2.0.tar.gz#md5=9c0f5d246ecfcf5f0905a$
Using version 3.2.1 (newest of versions: 3.2.1, 3.2.0)
Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/1e/ee/
295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-
3.2.1.tar.gz#md5=44656527ef3ac$
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-e_smjxjx/BeautifulSoup/setup.py) 
egg_info for package BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-e_smjxjx/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-e_smjxjx/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22

print "Unit tests have failed!"

                              ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-
e_smjxjx/BeautifulSoup
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in 
run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, 
bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in 
prepare_files
req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in 
call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed 
with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e_smjxjx/BeautifulSoup
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the content from "/root/.pip/pip.log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I uninstalled pip and installed pip again. This fix the error. Probably there were badly installed dependencies.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.